# How to prove $f(U,V)=||A-UVU^T||_F^2$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

I think one way is to verify if both $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial U^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial V^2}$ are postive semi-definite, is there other way to prove it?

Comment: Take $A=0$, and $U,V$ to be scalars. Show that the resulting function $(u,v) \mapsto u^4v^2$ is **not** convex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Positive definite matrix check, eigenvalue test. But for doing that you need to simplify the expression.